# Regex optional group match after specific words

Tags: regex

Regex:

```
(\d+).*?((?:[a-z][a-z\s?]+)).*?((?:court|ct|street|st)).*?(UNT\s?[\d\w].*|#\s?[\d\w].*)/ig
```

Matching

```
119 testing str test court #123

119 testing stret test court # 123

119 testing strt ct UNT 123

119 testing st UNT dsff

123 testing blah ct
```

My current regex is capturing correctly on the first 4 entries. How can I make everything involving # and UNT optional so my final "123 testing blah ct" can have capturing groups too?

Comment: What does this `\ig` do?

Comment: Add a question mark. `(UNT\s?[\d\w].*|#\s?[\d\w].*)?` Also the `\d` is not needed in that character class `\w` includes numbers.

Comment: Adding ? to the end works, but it breaks grouping if # or unt is included

Comment: Maybe `(\d+).*?([a-z][a-z\s?]+)(court|ct|street|st)(\h+(?:UNT)?\h*\w+)?(?:\h*#\h*\d+)?` https://regex101.com/r/UPhuds/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just make the ending optional, it won't match if it don't have to.
Have to induce it to continue.

That can be done with the EOL anchor `$`.

*Note that this part `[a-z\s?]` is a class that matches a-z or whitespace or question mark literal.*
Not sure if that's what you meant.

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/YYM34l/1)

`(?im)(\d+).*?((?:[a-z](?:[a-z]|[^\S\r\n])+)).*?((?:court|ct|street|st)).*?((?:UNT|\#)[^\S\r\n]?\w.*)?$`

Explained:

```
 (?im)                                  # Modifiers: ignore case, multi-line

 ( \d+ )                                # (1)
 .*? 
 (                                      # (2 start)
      (?:
           [a-z] 
           (?: [a-z] | [^\S\r\n] )+
      )
 )                                      # (2 end)
 .*? 
 (                                      # (3 start)
      (?: court | ct | street | st )
 )                                      # (3 end)
 .*? 
 (                                      # (4 start)
      (?: UNT | \# )
      [^\S\r\n]? \w .* 
 )?                                     # (4 end)

 $                                      # End of line (or string)
```

Comment: Updated to replace whitespace without cr/lf's.